# How to return an object with all rows and count of all rows

Tags: json, sql-server, object, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that returns 20 rows based on page number:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_GET_ALL
    @PAGE INT
AS
    SELECT * 
    FROM Item
    ORDER BY ID
        OFFSET (@PAGE - 1) * 20 ROWS
        FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY
```

When I consume the `API` the result is like this

```
[
    {id:1, name:"name1"},
    {id:2, name:"name2"},
    {id:3, name:"name3"},
    {id:4, name:"name4"},
    {id:5, name:"name5"},
    {id:6, name:"name6"},
    {id:7, name:"name7"},
    ....
]
```

I want to return the total count of all rows in the same query to set up web pagination. for example

```
{
    count: 1000,
    rows:[
            {id:1, name:"name1"},
            {id:2, name:"name2"},
            {id:3, name:"name3"},
            {id:4, name:"name4"},
            {id:5, name:"name5"},
            {id:6, name:"name6"},
            {id:7, name:"name7"},
            ....
        ]   
}
```

I don't want to do two requests to get the rows and the total count of all the rows.

Comment: Conceptually these are two queries nonetheless; trying to stuff both results in one query is possible, but isn't going to lead to a more efficient approach. Consider using an `OUTPUT` parameter in the stored procedure to pass the total. Better yet, if you're really going to be paging through lots of rows this way consider keyset pagination, because `OFFSET ... FETCH` tends to not do well on the performance end as the offsets increase, and also runs the risk of duplicated or omitted rows if the data changes inbetween calls.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: You could potentially add `[count] = COUNT(*) OVER()` window function to your query, but that would add count to every record in the result. (For paged queries, as yours appears to be, you would need to pre-calculate count and add it to the final select for the same effect.) Alternatives are to package up the results as XML or JSON where you can build a result layout as you illustrated above.